# Querying the ContentProvider for certain IDs

Tags: android, android-cursor, android-cursorloader

I have a contacts table and I need to get only certain IDs.

Imagine I have 10 contacts with ids from 1 to 10 and I want to get a `Cursor` with contacts 1 and 2.

A working code would be:

```
new CursorLoader(MyContentProvider.CONTACT_CONTENT_URI, null,
MyContentProvider.CONTACT_COLUMN_ID + " IN  ( 1, 2 )",
null, null);
```

My problem is that I am unable to use the `selectionArgs` parameter since the escaping would break the query.

Can you think of a way of using the `selectionArgs` parameters and making this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `selectionArgs` you can only use it like

```
String selection = "column IN (?, ?, ?)";
String[] selectionArgs = { "1", "2", "3" };
```

You need to build the `"( ?, ?, ? )"` string based on the number of arguments at runtime though. E.g.

```
private static String getSelection(int args) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(MyContentProvider.CONTACT_COLUMN_ID + " IN  (");
    boolean first = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < args; i ++) {
        if (first) {
            first = false;
        } else {
            sb.append(',');
        }
        sb.append('?');
    }
    sb.append(')');
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: At best, this will only work for a `ContentProvider` backed by SQLite or another SQL-compliant database. Now, in this case, the OP presumably is querying the OP's own `ContentProvider` and can ensure that this will work, but this is not a safe technique where you do not control the `ContentProvider` implementation.

Comment: A `ContentProvider`ish way would be to use `Uri` [query parameters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#getQueryParameter%28java.lang.String%29) which has to be implemented by the `ContentProvider` though. The whole `selection` / `selectionArgs` API of `ContentProvider` is too SQL centric.

Comment: @CommonsWare: That's ok for me, the `ContentProvider` will not get exported.